# How to add thumbnail to category in topmenu prestashop

Tags: prestashop

my question is about ,how to add thumbnail image before text to category in topmenu prestashop - via backend upload image to category

please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: edit code in `blocktopmenu.php` :

```
//2FR3
$thumb = $category['id_category'].'-0_thumb.jpg';
if(file_exists(_PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_.$thumb)) {
    $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$category['name'].'"><img src="'.$this->context->link->getMediaLink(_THEME_CAT_DIR_.$thumb).'" alt="'.Tools::SafeOutput($category['name']).'" title="'.Tools::SafeOutput($category['name']).'" /><br />'. $category['name'].'</a>';
} else {
    $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$category['name'].'">'. $category['name'].'</a>';
}
```